# jQuery selectors and dynamic content

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

OK I am so confused, hopefully someone can tell me what I am missing.

I have a class which I am using to listen to click events on  and  classname: .action-panel-button

I am trying to get a single selector line for jQuery but it's only working if I use two different ones:

I have an  link which fires when using this for the selector:

```
// Only fires for content loaded initially with the page, 
// not on dynamic content
$('.action-panel-button').on('click', function() {
    console.log(a link fired);
});
```

The above doesn't work for dynamically added content. So I updated it to:

```
// Only fires for content loaded dynamically via ajax, 
// not on content originally loaded with the page
$(document).on('click', '.action-panel-button', function() {
    console.log(a link fired);
});
```

I thought the second one should work for both. What am I missing?

Comment: the second one should work are you getting any errors?

Comment: Check the class `action-panel-button` is added on dynamically added links and let us know the jquery version which you are using.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear at the end there, the click is fired for the dynamic content using the second (bottom) option, but when I use that one the top link that is on the page initial load doesn't work.

Im using jquery-2.1.10

Comment: can explain this `but when I use that one the top link that is on the page initial load doesn't work.`

Answer (score 0):

> This works fine for both default content and dynamically added content, May be this will help you.

```js
$( "body" ).delegate( "p", "click", function() {
  $( this ).after( "<p>Another paragraph!</p>" );
});
```

```css
  p {
    background: yellow;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px;
  }
  p.over {
    background: #ccc;
  }
  span {
    color: red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<p>Click me!</p>
<span></span>
```